# I want to call a function (that is in the child functional component) in a parent component but i don't know how to pass it to its parent React.js

Tags: reactjs

so I have this function in the child component

```
const checkPercentage = () => {
    let count = 0;
    for(let list of lists){
      if(list.title === "Done"){
        setDoneId(list.listId);
      }
    }
    for (let task of tasks) {
      if (task.listId === doneId) {
        count++;
        setDoneCount(count);
      }
      setPercentDone((doneCount / tasks.length) * 100);
    }
    console.log("done count")
    console.log(doneCount)
    console.log(percentDone)
    console.log(tasks)
  };
```

and I want to call it in the parent component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: they're using class components but I'm using functional components so it won't work with me but thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer for the similar question, I have create the following example that includes the code you have provided in the question. Please note the definition differences between the `cannotBeCalledFromParent` function and `childFunctionCallableFromParent` or `checkPercentage` function.

**Parent component:**

```typescript
import ChildComponent from "./test-child";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function ParentComponent() {
    // In order to gain access to the child component instance,
    // you need to assign it to a `ref`, so we call `useRef()` to get one
    const childRef = useRef();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Here is parent component</h1>
            {/* sent the childRef to the child component as a value of the 'ref' property */ }
            <ChildComponent ref={childRef} test='from parent through props' />
            <button onClick={() => childRef.current.childFunctionCallableFromParent()}>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child component:**

```typescript
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";

const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

    const cannotBeCalledFromParent = () => {
        console.log("cannot be called from parent");
    }

    // The component instance will be extended
    // with whatever you return from the callback passed
    // as the second argument
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            childFunctionCallableFromParent() {
                // this function has access to all members of the child component
                // for example 'props'
                console.log("child function called: ", props.test);
                // example on calling other functions from the component
                cannotBeCalledFromParent();
                this.checkPercentage();
            },

            // this function can also be called directly from parent
            checkPercentage() {
                let count = 0;
                for(let list of lists){
                  if(list.title === "Done"){
                    setDoneId(list.listId);
                  }
                }
                for (let task of tasks) {
                  if (task.listId === doneId) {
                    count++;
                    setDoneCount(count);
                  }
                  setPercentDone((doneCount / tasks.length) * 100);
                }
                console.log("done count")
                console.log(doneCount)
                console.log(percentDone)
                console.log(tasks)
            } 
        }
    });
    
    return (
        <div> I am child component </div>
    )
});

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: Did this work for you?